# While I'm trying to run pip install qd, I'm seeing the following error:

Tags: python

```
Collecting qd
  Using cached qd-0.8.9.tar.gz (3.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from qd) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: diversipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from qd) (0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11==2.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from qd) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from qd) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from diversipy->qd) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from h5py->qd) (1.5.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: qd
  Building wheel for qd (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qd
  Running setup.py clean for qd
Failed to build qd
Installing collected packages: qd
    Running setup.py install for qd ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kaa2z4nv/qd_80230612208f4be9a0be0b1da544d3cb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kaa2z4nv/qd_80230612208f4be9a0be0b1da544d3cb/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-9uv_s7te/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7/qd Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: I think you should check if it needs some extra requirements which are not installed with it

Comment: Not sure if it'll help but worth trying: `pip install qd --no-cache-dir`

Comment: Could you please post the command you used to install this module ?